# Trying to remove-item but it's not getting removed

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, get-childitem

I'm thinning out my backup files with a powershell script, and I know I have the correct filenames, but for some reason when I use remove-item, the item doesn't get removed and no exception is thrown.  This is what it looks like:

```
try{
   $Drive = "E:\temp\"
   $deleteTime = -42
   $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays($deleteTime) #files older than 6 weeks

   #get files in folder older than deleteTime and with signature of *junk.vhd* (to be changed later)
   $temp1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive -filter "*junk.vhd*" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit} | Select -Expand Name  #this has 5 files in list

   #will delete every other file
   for($i=$temp1.GetLowerBound(0);$i -le $temp1.GetUpperBound(0);$i+=2) {
      $name = $temp1[$i]
      Write-Host "removing $name" #prints correct file names to screen
      Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive -include $name | Remove-Item -recurse -force #this is handling correct files but they aren't deleted for some reason
   }
}#try
Catch [Exception] {
   #nothing is caught
   Write-Host "here"
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why it's finding and Write-Host the correct filenames to remove, but the Remove-Item isn't removing them?

I was looking at [removal a little different](http://www.systemcentercentral.com/recursively-delete-read-only-directories-subdirectories-and-files-with-no-prompt-in-powershell/) example, but everything looks good.

Comment: I think your problem is Get-ChildItem.  Your $name might be correct, but Get-ChildItem is not working as expected.  Try using -Filter instead of -Include.  (I don't remember why, just that Include and Exclude have some quirks.)  To test it, break up the Get-ChildItem / Remove-Item into two steps, assigning the result of GCI to a variable that you can inspect before passing it to Remove-Item.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this line:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive -include $name | Remove-Item -recurse -force #this is handling correct files but they aren't deleted for some reason
```

with this:

```
Remove-Item $temp1[i].FullName -force -recurse
```

Since you already got the full patrh to the file, I don't feel it's necessary to call `Get-ChilItem` again and pass it through the pipeline, instead you just feed Remove-Item with the FUllName property which is the full path to thew file.